# How To Use ElasticSearch In Vertx Java With EventBus?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, vert.x

Can Somebody let me know how to use elasticsearch in vertx for java.I have used eventbus but i couldn't able to get it done. New to Vertx. Any help will be appreciated.
I have tried it this way. Index name is movies. Index_type is movie. And ID is 1. I want to delete this record.Using Default Configuration.

```
 JsonObject delete = new JsonObject(); 
 delete.put("action", "delete");
 delete.put("_index", "movies");
 delete.put("_type", "movie");
 delete.put("_id", "1");
 vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
     vertx.eventBus().send("et.vertx.elasticsearch", delete);
 })listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it's a vertx service for Elasticsearch...that should get
you going.

https://github.com/englishtown/vertx-elasticsearch-service

Comment: i have followed this earlier but there was some error because vertx couldn't able to load service. But now i have implemented my own service to include it.. Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This repo is tasted with elastic search 6.1. Originally Forked from ef-labs/vertx-elasticsearch-service but diverged a lot since then. It will good to get started with ES with Vert.x:

https://github.com/hubrick/vertx-elasticsearch-service